# How to sort an array when values have string and numeric both

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array i want to sort it into ascending order.

Below is array i have.

```
Array

[0] => 101.6mm x 101.6mm 
[1] => 50.8mm x 50.8mm 
[3] => 76.2mm x 76.2mm 
[4] => 100mm x 100mm 
[5] => 15mm x 15mm 
[6] => 20mm x 20mm 
[8] => 25mm x 25mm 
[10] => 30mm x 30mm 
[12] => 40mm x 40mm 
[13] => 50mm x 50mm 
[14] => 60mm x 60m 
[15] => 80mm x 80mm
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean values are strings which contains some product dimensions and you want to sort according those 2 dimensions inside ?

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas, Correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to write custom string parts comparison function for `usort()`:

```
$products = [
                "101.6mm x 101.6mm",
                "50.8mm x 50.8mm",
                "76.2mm x 76.2mm",
                "100mm x 100mm",
                "15mm x 15mm",
                "20mm x 20mm",
                "50mm x 50.2mm",
                "25mm x 25mm",
                "30mm x 45mm",
                "30mm x 30mm",
                "40mm x 40mm",
                "50mm x 50mm",
                "60mm x 60m",
                "80mm x 80mm",
    ];

usort($products,
    function($a, $b) {
        list($vals_a, $vals_b) = [explode('x', $a), explode('x', $b)];
        $vals_a[0] = preg_replace('/(\s|mm)/mui', '',$vals_a[0]);
        $vals_a[1] = preg_replace('/(\s|mm)/mui', '',$vals_a[1]);
        $vals_b[0] = preg_replace('/(\s|mm)/mui', '',$vals_b[0]);
        $vals_b[1] = preg_replace('/(\s|mm)/mui', '',$vals_b[1]);
        if ($vals_a[0] < $vals_b[0])
            return -1;
        elseif ($vals_a[0] > $vals_b[0])
            return +1;
        else {
            if ($vals_a[1] < $vals_b[1])
                return -1;
            elseif ($vals_a[1] > $vals_b[1])
                return +1;
            else return 0;
        }
    });

var_dump($products);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert these strings to float values. Can be done easily with PHP.

```
$arr = array(

    "101.6mm x 101.6mm",
    "50.8mm x 50.8mm", 
    "76.2mm x 76.2mm", 
    "100mm x 100mm",
    "15mm x 15mm",
    "20mm x 20mm",
    "25mm x 25mm",
    "30mm x 30mm", 
    "40mm x 40mm",
    "50mm x 50mm",
    "60mm x 60mm",
    "80mm x 80mm",

);

$endArray = array();

foreach($arr as $item){

    $parts = explode("x", $item);

    array_push($endArray, array(

          (float)filter_var( $parts[0], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION ),
          (float)filter_var( $parts[1], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION )

    ));



}
echo '<pre>';
sort($endArray);
print_r($endArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort as numeric with the flag `SORT_NUMERIC`

```
asort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

Using this array:

```
$array = ['101.6mm x 101.6mm',
                  '50.8mm x 50.8mm',
                  '76.2mm x 76.2mm',
                  '100mm x 100mm',
                  '15mm x 15mm',
                  '20mm x 20mm',
                  '25mm x 25mm',
                  '30mm x 30mm',
                  '40mm x 40mm',
                  '50mm x 50mm',
                  '60mm x 60m',
                  '80mm x 80mm'];

asort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

`SORT_NUMERIC` produced this list:

> - 15mm x 15mm
> - 20mm x 20mm
> - 25mm x 25mm
> - 30mm x 30mm
> - 40mm x 40mm
> - 50mm x 50mm
> - 50.8mm x 50.8mm
> - 60mm x 60m
> - 76.2mm x 76.2mm
> - 80mm x 80mm
> - 100mm x 100mm
> - 101.6mm x 101.6mm

which looks good to me :)

Comment: No it is not :-) SORT_NUMERIC just sorts by first number - that's why by co-incidence you get good results. Try to sort array with row `"50mm x 50.2mm"` and one row `"50mm x 50mm"` somewhere below :-)

Comment: The products only seemed to be square, but that was an assumption based on the sample size.  I agree it won't work if that is not a correct assumption :)